# How to resolve Nifty cloud send push notification error from monaca (android)?

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, monaca

I have implemented nifty cloud for push notification service in **monaca platform(android)**.
I can receive push notification send from nifty cloud mobile backend.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    console.log("app is ready");
    window.NCMB.monaca.setDeviceToken(
        "a111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111",//Application Key
        "b111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111", //Client Key
        "22222222222" //fcm sender id  
    );
}, false);
```

But i also need to send push notification from android. For this this i am following [this](http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/sdkguide/javascript/push.html)

```
// "Application key" and "Client Key"
     var ncmb = new 
NCMB("a111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111", "b111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"); // 
            var push = new ncmb.Push();
            $scope.pushSend = function () {
                push.set({
                    "immediateDeliveryFlag": true,
                    "target": ["android"],
                    "message": "Please input your test messge",
                    "deliveryExpirationTime": "3 day"
                });
                push.send()
                    .then(function (message) {
                        console.log(message);
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
            };
```

Now, I'm getting this error [image: error]

this is my request header [image: request header]

I can see that in my request header **X-NCMB-Apps-Session-Token** is missing.
So why **X-NCMB-Apps-Session-Token** is not present in my request header and how to solve 404 (Not Found) problem.